# Python glob.glob(dir) Memory Error

Tags: python, posix, glob

I'm dealing with a memory issue when searching a folder with milions of files. Does anyone know how to overcome this situation? Is there some way to put a limit of files that glob will search? So it could be executed in chunks?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./lb2_lmanager", line 533, in <module>
   main(sys.argv[1:])
 File "./lb2_lmanager", line 318, in main
    matched = match_files(policy.directory, policy.file_patterns)
  File "./lb2_lmanager", line 32, in wrapper
    res = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "./lb2_lmanager", line 380, in match_files
    listing = glob.glob(directory)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/glob.py", line 16, in glob
    return list(iglob(pathname))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/glob.py", line 43, in iglob
    yield os.path.join(dirname, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/posixpath.py", line 70, in join
   path += '/' + b
MemoryError
```

Comment: Have you tried iglob rather than glob?

Comment: Please a code example!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `generators` instead of `lists`.

To understand what generators are read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python)

```
import glob
dir_list = glob.iglob(YOUR_DIRECTORY)
for file in dir_list:
    print file
```

Change `YOUR_DIRECTORY` to the directory that you would like to list.

Comment: I'll try iglob instead of glob.